# Opening Web page from As3 to replace current iFrame

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

How Can I open a web page from the As3  so that it replaces current iFrame (and Flash object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to open the web page into the iframe or do you want to replace the whole page containing the iframe?

The former:

```
import flash.net.*;    
navigateToURL( new URLRequest("url-of-the-page-to-be-opened"), "_self" );
```

The latter:

```
import flash.net.*;    
navigateToURL( new URLRequest("url-of-the-page-to-be-opened"), "_top" );
```